# How to get those url(s) from carrierwave once successfully uploaded multiple images and format like below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
{
    "image_url": [
      "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800936.jpg",
      "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800937.jpg",
      "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800938.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Here's my path to custom folder when saving the images:

```
def store_dir
       "images/folder1/#{model.uuid}"
end
```

Here's my params permit:

```
def folder1_params
       params.permit({images: []})
end
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have image url as same as I mentioned above. But what I'm getting is 
`"url": "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800936.jpg"`
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to send as `JSON` response of API call.

I think changing your controller will help to get this format.

Like normally it will provide you below format.

```
{
    "image_url": [
      { url: "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800936.jpg"},
      { url: "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800937.jpg"},
      { url: "/images/folder1/554adeec-1b54-45db-a911-a7fb878d1820/image-1525800938.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

So the simplest way I can suggest is
1. Add a method in your model.

in controller while sending JSON response.

`render json: { data: model_name.merge(image_urls: image_urls.map(&:url)) }`